# "Learning occupancy grid maps with forward sensor models, S.Thurn,2008" a formula that is difficult to overcome

Tags: artificial-intelligence, probability-theory, probabilistic-algorithms

I am reviewing the document" Learning occupancy grid maps with forward sensor models, S.Thrun, 2008" (http://faculty.iiit.ac.in/~mkrishna/ThrunOccGrid.pdf)

i am really confused about formula (26), which is merged by formula (22), (24), (25) in an "intersection of probabilities" computed in (22),(24),(25). So, it should be a product of factors in (22),(24),(25). If it is correct, the first factor of (26), 1/sqrt(2*π*σ), should be powered.

any one can tell me why 1/sqrt(2*π*σ) isn't powered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vector $c_t$ has exactly one coordinate which is 1, and the rest are 0s. You can check that if, for example, $c_{t,k}=1$, when you substitute $c_{t,k}=1$ and $c_{t,\ell}=0$ for all $\ell \neq k$ in (26) you get (22). The same happens for (24) and (25).

Comment: thanks, it 's really useful. But could you let me know the rule author used to establish (26) from (22) (24) (25)? it doesn't look like a probabilistic theory.

Comment: The author used an ad hoc method.

Comment: I cant find any useful doc about it. could you recommend me a document about ad hoc method

Comment: Look up "ad hoc" in the dictionary.

Comment: Could you help me one more in the same paper? formula [40], Why did author set it as "min"? it is maximization step, perhaps it should be "max"

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it separately.